# Unable to share message to WhatsApp

Tags: windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I initially developed an app in iOS using PhoneGap and used the following plugin to share message via WhatsApp.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Now I am adding to create a Windows Phone 8 version of the app, but I am unable to share to WhatsApp because the code file for the Windows version does not have the `shareviawhatsapp` method.

Is there any plugin which allows us to share via WhatsApp on Windows Phone using PhoneGap?

Comment: Fork this project and write whatsapp for C# yourself, and send a PR to the project. That's how open-source works.

Answer (score 0):

No, there won't be.

This is because Windows Phone sharing works differently. You should do a normal text share, this will trigger the share UI and if the user has WhatsApp installed it will be listed as a share target. See [this](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/implement-sharing-to-facebook--twitter-in-windows-phone) for some more background on sharing.